# AWS ec2 windows login error saying An authentication error has occured. The local security authority cannot be contacted

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-ec2

After creating an ec2 windows machine from a custom AMI. I am able to get the admin password. However when I try to login to the machine.

I get the RDP error saying `'An authentication error has occurred. The local security authority cannot be contacted. This could be due to an expired password.'`

The password isn't expired and there is no issue with the AMI as when I create another instance from the same it works fine.

Comment: Started having similar problems myself. Today I am unable to RDP into any of my AWS VMs across multiple accounts. Me smells issues here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I turned off NLA on the Host server I was able to login, but obviously that's not a reasonable answer.

Turned out to be BitDefender, once I turned off protection I could connect to all my EC2 VMS.

-Just a note for me. This was only blocking VMS I was connecting to through ec2 Public DNS.

Comment: I spent an entire weekend trying to fix this problem (was trying to access an Azure VM so I could do an assessment exercise for a job interview) and sure enough it *was* Bitdefender's fault. Thank you v.v.v.much.